# Not able to launch slave-agent.jnlp

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to execute job using local system as slave. 
When I try to launch slave-agent.jnlp from jenkins as well as through command line it doesn't starts. Also, through command line it doesn't shows any error.

please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try running the slave-agent jnlp file in verbose mode. I have had the same issue in the past and verbose mode usually gives more info. To run in verbose mode you will have to add -versose to your javaws command. Download the slave-agent.jnlp file to your slave machine. Now from the command line execute "javaws -verbose slave-agent.jnlp" (assuming you are CDed into the directory that has the jnlp file)

Comment: Is there any error message? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I have used -verbose it says "Launching: c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe -classpath c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar and so on...... but it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Unless you provide more info, it is hard to understand the issue. Try posting screenshots of what you get, that might help.

Comment: You need to edit your question and copy and paste the log for us so we can see ... 
Also make sure you have 'Remote FS root' set in your node's configuration. usualy removing that folder's content (root folder)  will do the trick if thats the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jenkins slave is started from the system where the job is expected to run later on.
Open the nodes page in firefox and click on the Launch button.

For more information:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart